# How to change background colour of left menu in Inspinia

Tags: css, inspinia

The [Inspinia](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/inspinia-responsive-admin-theme-WB0R5L90S) AngularJS framework has a demo [here](http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0R5L90S) for those who don't use it.

For the life of me, I cannot see how to change the background colour of the navigation menu on the left. It should be simple, but I just can't find it, even using the Chrome developer console.

[image]

---

[Update] I want to change the color programmatically from AngularJS, what's the best way to do that? Maybe add an Id to the `background div`?

Comment: there is no background color defined in sidebar, its the background color of body, and the middle content section has light grey bg color, so change the body color and sidebar color will be changed.

Comment: Feel free to post that as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make some changes, according to the images below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I hope to have helped in some way

Answer (score 2):

`.nav-header` and other elements in your sidebar use `background-image` and those images are opaque, not showing the background color. You need to check (and reset) `background-image` property of items in your sidebar for this.

Example:

```
.nav-header {
    background-image: unset;
}
#side-menu {
    background-color: #933;
}
.nav > li.active {
    background-color: #833;
}
```

Keep inspecting your elements until you find what rule sets the `backgorund-image`, `background-color` or `background` (shorthand) for the element, copy the selector of the currently applying rule and place it in your own stylesheet, changing the value of the property. Make sure you load it after the rest of your stylesheets.

Answer (score 2):

i guess this will help u

```
body{
  background-color: #F44336;
}
.nav-header{
  background-color: #F44336;
  background-image: none;
}
.nav > li.active{
  background: #c7635b;
}
.navbar-default .nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .nav > li > a:focus{
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `background-color` defined in sidebar, its the `background-color` of body, and the middle content section has light grey bg `color`, so change the `body-color` and sidebar color will be changed.